# deepstream.io with python flask

Tags: python, node.js, flask, deepstream.io

Please can some one guide me or point me towards the right path.
I want to use http://deepstream.io/ with python flask.
My web application has python flask and there are some events to be passed to clients. So how will i communicate with deepstream.io from flask app.
I went through the documents and but they all are related to JS side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you can make tcp connection to port 6021

Answer (score 0):

Currently deepstream only comes with a client for browsers/NodeJS. We intend to offer a range of clients in different languages going forward, but the topmost priority will be a Java client I'm afraid.